# Big DJVU with multiple pages opens just one page

Tags: djvu

I have a file that, through testing with **trID** (Software used to check the format of a particular file), is identified as a DJVU file, but when I open it in DJViewer **it only opens the first page and no more**, although I know for sure (when I previously opened it in another software, proprietary software) that it contains more than 100 pages . How can it be analyzed in depth and opened in its true form?

Comment: Try an alternative viewer, such as Sumatra PDF or Calibre's viewer. See https://www.lifewire.com/djvu-file-2620674 There are infinite possibilities.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I tried the readers you suggested in your previous comment, but nothing came of it, yet I see only one page file.
Is it possible that the extra pages are stored in the DJVU file as layers and not as separate pages?
If so, how do I see which layers are in the DJVU file and how to separate them?

Comment: Sorry, that's beyond my area of expertise. Perhaps the Wikipedia article might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DjVu